# Change the encoding of the textfield

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, textarea, titanium

I am trying to type in arabic into a textfield in Titanium(creating an iOS app).

I want to change the encoding settings of the textfield to UTF-8. Need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You can convert easily one way or the other.

```
NSString *foo = someTextField.text;
NSData *data = [foo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *fooString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For specific appcelerator encoding types you need to refer to their documentation.

[Appcelerator Encoding Spec](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Encoding_Spec)

Comment: but this is in xcode right ? I need to do it in Titanium and I'm not sure if this will work.